# spinner item is not displayed on android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have to develop android spinner application.

Here, the `spinner list item` is not displayed. Why this error is occurring here. Please help me and give me a solution for this.

I have used below code:

```
public class NewCustomer extends Activity{
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://admin.com";
private final String URL = "http://10.0.0.75:8085/AdminLogin/services/InsertSpinner?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://admin.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
Button btninsert;
String selectedItem;
Spinner spinner;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_customer);

    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

                               insertValues();
                       } 

         });
     }
     public void insertValues(){
      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


    PropertyInfo bcoun =new PropertyInfo();
    bcoun.setName("Bcountry");
    bcoun.setValue(selectedItem);
    bcoun.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(bcoun); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
     androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        result.setText(response.toString());

       }
      catch(Exception e){

        }
    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    //Dynamically generate a spinner data 
    createSpinnerDropDown();

     }
        private void createSpinnerDropDown() {

    //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tf_country);

    //Array list of animals to display in the spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Intent in = getIntent();
    list.add("United Status");
       list.add("Afghanistan");
       list.add("Aland Islands");
       list.add("Albania");
       list.add("Algeria");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.row, R.id.country, list);


  // adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setPrompt("Choose a Country");

  // spinner.setTextColor("#FF0000");
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

     }
      public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

      selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

       }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

       }
```

I have to run application and click the spinner box selecting spinner item. But, here the spinner item is not displaying...why the spinner item is not display? Whats wrong in my code? Please help me.

Comment: for one, you are networking on the ui thread

Comment: Why are you creating spinner twice?

Comment: @Supreethks sorry for that..now i have created once ly.

Answer (score 0):

After i have to Call createSpinnerDropDown(); in onCreate Method .these is worked now well.